# Merge N log files maintaining the chronological order

Tags: c++, algorithm, external-sorting

I have N different log files coming from N different services running on our device. I want to merge the N files into a single file maintaining the chronological order. The file size can vary from few KB to GB.

The N log files have the same format, and it is like:

```
**********  LOGGING SESSION STARTED ************
* Hmsoa Version: 2.4.0.12
* Exe Path: c:\program files (x86)\silicon biosystems\deparray300a_driver\deparray300a_driver.exe
* Exe Version: 1.6.0.154
************************************************


TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,180 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'Connect'->Enter;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,196 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'Connect'->Exit=0;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,196 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'CCisProxyLocal CONNECT - ok'->Enter;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,196 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'CRecoveryAxesProxyLocal CONNECT - ok'->Enter;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,196 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'CAmplifierProxyLocalV3 CONNECT - ok'->Enter;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,196 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'SYSTEM_DIAGNOSIS_GET'->Enter;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,211 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'SYSTEM_DIAGNOSIS_GET'->Exit=0;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,211 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'LBL_SQUARE_SET'->Enter;
TIME = 2017/02/01 11:12:12,219 ; THID = 4924; CAT = ; LVL = 1000; LOG = API 'LBL_SQUARE_SET'->Exit=0;
```

Since I already have N different files, what I did so far is to apply an external sorting algorithm reading a single line for each file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include "boost\filesystem.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

static const boost::regex expression(R"(^(?:(?:TIME\s=\s\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s)|(?:@))([0-9:.,]+))");
static const boost::regex nameFileEx(R"(^[\d\-\_]+(\w+\s?\w+|\w+))");
static const std::string path("E:\\2017-02-01"); 
//static const std::string path("E:\\TestLog");

unsigned long time2Milleseconds(const std::string & time)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    if (sscanf_s(time.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d) >= 3)
        return a * 3600000 + b * 60000 + c * 1000 + d;
}

void readAllFilesUntilLine7(std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> & vifs)
{
    std::string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < vifs.size(); ++i)
    {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (lineNumber != 7 && std::getline(vifs[i].first, line))
        { 
            ++lineNumber;
        }
    }
}

void checkRegex(std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> & vifs, std::vector<unsigned long> & logTime, std::vector<std::string> & lines, int index, int & counter)
{
    std::string line;
    boost::smatch what;
    if (std::getline(vifs[index].first, line))
    {
        if (boost::regex_search(line, what, expression))
        {
            logTime[index] = time2Milleseconds(what[1]);
        }
        lines[index] = line;
    }
    else
    {
        --counter;
        logTime[index] = ULONG_MAX;
    }
}

void mergeFiles(std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> & vifs, std::vector<unsigned long> & logTime, std::vector<std::string> & lines, std::ofstream & file, int & counter)
{
    std::string line;
    boost::smatch what;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vifs.size(); ++i)
    {
        checkRegex(vifs, logTime, lines, i, counter);
    }
    index = min_element(logTime.begin(), logTime.end()) - logTime.begin();
    file << lines[index] << " --> " << vifs[index].second << "\n";
    while (true)
    {
        checkRegex(vifs, logTime, lines, index, counter);
        index = min_element(logTime.begin(), logTime.end()) - logTime.begin();
        if (0 == counter)
            break;
        file << lines[index] << " --> " << vifs[index].second << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int cnt = std::count_if(fs::directory_iterator(path),fs::directory_iterator(),static_cast<bool(*)(const fs::path&)>(fs::is_regular_file));
    std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> vifs(cnt);
    int index = 0;
    boost::smatch what;
    std::string file;
    for (fs::directory_iterator d(path); d != fs::directory_iterator(); ++d)
    {
        if (fs::is_regular_file(d->path()))
        {
            file = d->path().filename().string();
            if (boost::regex_search(file, what, nameFileEx))
            {
                vifs[index++] = std::make_pair(std::ifstream(d->path().string()), what[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<unsigned long> logTime(cnt, ULONG_MAX);
    std::vector<std::string> lines(cnt);
    std::ofstream filename(path + "\\TestLog.txt");
    readAllFilesUntilLine7(vifs);
    mergeFiles(vifs, logTime, lines, filename, cnt);
    filename.close();
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time = " << elapsed_secs << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It does exactly what it is supposed to do but it is slow. To merge 82 files with sizes ranging from 1 KB to 250 MB and create a final file with more than 6000000 lines it takes 70 minutes.

How can I speed up the algorithm? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I have implemented the version with the heap, too:

Data.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Data
{
public:
    Data(DWORD index,
         const std::string & line,
         ULONG time);
    ~Data();
    inline const ULONG getTime() const  {return time; }
    inline const DWORD getIndex() const { return index; }
    inline const std::string getLine() const { return line; }
private:
    DWORD index;
    std::string line;
    ULONG time;
};

class Compare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Data & lhs, const Data & rhs) { return lhs.getTime() > rhs.getTime(); };
};
```

Data.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Data.h"


Data::Data(DWORD i_index,
           const std::string & i_line,
           ULONG i_time)
    : index(i_index)
    , line(i_line)
    , time(i_time)
{
}


Data::~Data()
{
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
#include "boost\filesystem.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
#include <queue>
#include "Data.h"
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

static const boost::regex expression(R"(^(?:(?:TIME\s=\s\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s)|(?:@))([0-9:.,]+))");
static const boost::regex nameFileEx(R"(^[\d\-\_]+(\w+\s?\w+|\w+))");
static const std::string path("E:\\2017-02-01");
//static const std::string path("E:\\TestLog");

unsigned long time2Milleseconds(const std::string & time)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    if (sscanf_s(time.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d) >= 3)
        return a * 3600000 + b * 60000 + c * 1000 + d;
}

void initializeHeap(std::ifstream & ifs, std::priority_queue<Data, std::vector<Data>, Compare> & myHeap, const int index)
{
    ULONG time;
    std::string line;
    boost::smatch what;
    bool match = false;
    while (!match && std::getline(ifs, line))
    {
        if (boost::regex_search(line, what, expression))
        {
            time = time2Milleseconds(what[1]);
            myHeap.push(Data(index, line, time));
            match = true;
        }
    }
}

void checkRegex(std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> & vifs, std::priority_queue<Data, std::vector<Data>, Compare> & myHeap, ULONG time, const int index)
{
    std::string line;
    boost::smatch what;
    if (std::getline(vifs[index].first, line))
    {
        if (boost::regex_search(line, what, expression))
        {
            time = time2Milleseconds(what[1]);
        }
        myHeap.push(Data(index, line, time));
    }
}

void mergeFiles(std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> & vifs, std::priority_queue<Data, std::vector<Data>, Compare> & myHeap, std::ofstream & file)
{
    int index = 0;
    ULONG time = 0;
    while (!myHeap.empty())
    {
        index = myHeap.top().getIndex();
        time = myHeap.top().getTime();
        file << myHeap.top().getLine() << " --> " << vifs[index].second << "\n";
        myHeap.pop();
        checkRegex(vifs, myHeap, time, index);
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int cnt = std::count_if(fs::directory_iterator(path), fs::directory_iterator(), static_cast<bool(*)(const fs::path&)>(fs::is_regular_file));
    std::priority_queue<Data, std::vector<Data>, Compare> myHeap;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, std::string>> vifs(cnt);
    int index = 0;
    boost::smatch what;
    std::string file;
    for (fs::directory_iterator d(path); d != fs::directory_iterator(); ++d)
    {
        if (fs::is_regular_file(d->path()))
        {
            file = d->path().filename().string();
            if (boost::regex_search(file, what, nameFileEx))
            {
                vifs[index] = std::make_pair(std::ifstream(d->path().string()), what[1]);
                initializeHeap(vifs[index].first, myHeap, index);
                ++index;
            }
        }
    }
    std::ofstream filename(path + "\\TestLog.txt");
    mergeFiles(vifs, myHeap, filename);
    filename.close();
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time = " << elapsed_secs << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

After all this work, I realized that yesterday I run the program in Debug. Launching both the implementations in Release, I got the following results:

- Vector implementation: about 25 seconds
- Heap implementation: about 27 seconds

Thus, or my implementation with the heap structure is not optimized or the two implementation are equal in running time.

Is there something else I can do to speed up the execution?

Comment: For what it's worth, [GNU sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) has a `-m`/`--merge` option, to merge already-sorted files. It may be easier to use that than to write a new program.

Comment: I think as a first step, you should try to find out whether IO or processing (CPU) is the bottleneck here. (iotop?)

Comment: `file << lines[index] << std::endl;` This could be an issue. `std::endl` flushes (at least for the C++ standard library) the internal buffer. Better use `'\n'`.

Comment: Further, the `std::all_of` is not necessary if you keep a counter of files with more input. Decrease everytime when `std::getline` in `checkRegex` fails (due to EOF).

Comment: Also I think there's a bug / corner case: When the regex fails in `checkRegex`, you'll end up writing the previous line. `lines[index] = line;` should probably be run regardless of whether the regex matches or not.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done faster and with low memory.  Consider first:

- Read a single line from each file (so only `N` lines are in memory at any one time).
- Find the smallest of the `N` lines, output it.
- In memory, replace the value just output with the next line from the file that the current output came from (take care of the EOF case).

If `M` is the length of your output file (ie the length of all logs combined), then the trivial implementation would be `O(N * M)`.

However, the above can be improved by using a heap, which reduces the time to `O(M log N)`.  That is, put the `N` in-memory elements on the heap.  Pop off the top one to output the smallest element.  Then, when you read a new line, just throw the line back on the heap.

Comment: Except for the heap, that's exactly what the code already does, no?

Comment: @DanielJour The speed optimisation is the heap.  The memory optimisation is only having `N` lines in memory at the time, right?

Comment: I doubt that the heap will bring a real improvement here ... the example in the questions has 82 files. Searching linearly through 82 lines for the smallest one won't be significantly slower than having to construct a heap and managing the insertions and removals. The code in the question already uses only `N` lines: `std::vector<std::string> lines(cnt);` where `cnt` is the number of files, `N`.

Comment: @DanielJour `Log2(82)` is approx 6.357.  For the current implementation to benefit, the cost of heap management needs to be more than a factor of 12 than current handling.  I don't know how efficient C++ heaps are, but I think it is worth a shot to try it!

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for the tips. I have a doubt about using the heap. How can I link the min value (related with the timestamp of the line) in the heap with the line to insert into the file? The first idea that come up in my mind is to use an heap where each element is a `std::pair<unsigned long, std::string>`. Is it right? or is there another better solution?

Comment: @BugsFree Yes, I would do something like that.  They need to be stored together.